# Triggers logic causes error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, logic

I'm making MySql database, where I have **film** table:

- id
- title
- amount
- available
- description

and **copy** table with foreign key *film_id*:

- id
- film_id

And now I've written after delete trigger **on copy**:

```
UPDATE `film`
            SET available = available - 1
WHERE OLD.film_id = id;
```

And now I would like to write before delete trigger **on film**,
due to fact that film is contrained by copy so I write:

```
DELETE FROM copy WHERE copy.film_id = OLD.id;
```

Here error occurs:

> Can't update table 'film' in stored function/trigger because it
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

***I would like to delete film -> delete copy -> update film (ERROR)***

Comment: If you delete a film (i.e. a row in film table) in the first step, how can you update the film reocord (the one that is deleted) in the third step? Does not seem logical.

Comment: @DarshanMehta If I want to delete film I must delete all copies where copy.film_id = OLD.id, but it triggers also update on film and that causes problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you do not need the `trigger` at all. Instead, you can configure `FOREIGN KEY` in such a way that entries in `copy` table will get deleted if a parent record in `film` gets deleted. Have a look at MySQL's documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). You need to use `CASCADE` option:

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and
>   automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
>   Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported.

This is how the `FOREIGN KEY` syntax will look like:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_film_id FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES film(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```